# How to join continue line seperated with ellipses (...) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
''' 
   This is single line. 
   This is second long line 
   ... continue from previous line. 
   This third single line. 
'''
```

I want to join lines which separated by ellipsis(...). This I want to do in Python. The long line is separated by new line (\n) and ellipsis (...). I am reading this file line by line and doing some operation on specific lines, but continue line ends with new line (\n) and next line starts with ellipsis (...). Because of this I am not able to get full line to do specific operation.

The lines I have took as example were from big file (lines more than 800). The python utility parse the files, search lines with specific keywords and replace some portion of the line with new syntax. This I want to do on multiple files.

Please advise me.

Comment: What do you mean about *join lines* ? `text.split('...')`?

Comment: Do you mean the    `This is second long line` and `... continue from previous line. ` should be `This is second long line continue from previous line.`?

Comment: @Kevin, Yes I want same output.

Comment: Then, check Michael's 

answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the lines on line breaks, and then loop through and add the ellipses lines to the previous line, like so:

```
lines = lines.split('\n')
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    line = line.strip().lstrip()
    if line.startswith('...') and i != 0:
        lines[i - 1] = lines[i - 1].strip().lstrip() + line.replace('...', '')
        del lines[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
delim = '...'
text = '''This is single line.
          This is second long line
          ... continue from previous line.
          This third single line.
       '''

# here we're building a list containing each line
# we'll clean up the leading and trailing whitespace
# by mapping Python's `str.strip` method onto each
# line
# this gives us:
#
#   ['This is single line.', 'This is second long line', 
#    '... continue from previous line.', 'This third single line.', '']
cleaned_lines = map(str.strip, text.split('\n'))

# next, we'll join our cleaned string on newlines, so we'll get back
# the original string without excess whitespace
# this gives us:
#
#   This is single line.
#   This is second long line
#   ... continue from previous line.
#   This third single line.
cleaned_str = '\n'.join(cleaned_lines)

# now, we'll split on our delimiter '...'
# this gives us:
#
#   ['This is single line.\nThis is second long line\n', 
#    ' continue from previous line.\nThis third single line.\n']
split_str = cleaned_str.split(delim)

# lastly, we'll now strip off trailing whitespace (which includes)
# newlines. Then, we'll join our list together on an empty string
new_str = ''.join(map(str.rstrip, split_str))

print new_str
```

which outputs

```
This is single line.
This is second long line continue from previous line.
This third single line.
```

Comment: This wouldn't remove the new line after "this is second long line." So it actually returns:
        This is single line.\n
         This is second long line\n
          continue from previous line.\n
         This third single line.

Comment: @Michael, Thank you for a very neat and detail answer. The lines I have took as example were from big file (lines more than 800). The python utility parse the files, search lines with specific keywords and replace some portion of the line with new syntax. This I want to do on multiple files.